# What should I do if my server is under the attack?

Tags: server, security, firewall, ufw, logging

I have a mail server on Ubuntu 20.04. Yesterday I set up UFW firewall which looks like:

```
root@vmi514622:~# ufw status verbose
Status: active
Logging: on (low)
Default: deny (incoming), allow (outgoing), disabled (routed)
New profiles: skip

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
22/tcp                     LIMIT IN    Anywhere
80/tcp                     ALLOW IN    Anywhere                   # accept Apache
443/tcp                    ALLOW IN    Anywhere                   # accept HTTPS connections
1194/udp                   ALLOW IN    Anywhere                   # OpenVPN server
Anywhere                   DENY IN     49.88.112.75
465/tcp                    ALLOW IN    Anywhere
587/tcp                    ALLOW IN    Anywhere
22/tcp (v6)                LIMIT IN    Anywhere (v6)
80/tcp (v6)                ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)              # accept Apache
443/tcp (v6)               ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)              # accept HTTPS connections
1194/udp (v6)              ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)              # OpenVPN server
465/tcp (v6)               ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
587/tcp (v6)               ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
```

Today I get an email with this log which shows hundreds of attempts to log in as root:

```
################### Logwatch 7.5.2 (07/22/19) ####################
        Processing Initiated: Tue Mar  2 06:25:06 2021
        Date Range Processed: yesterday
                              ( 2021-Mar-01 )
                              Period is day.
        Detail Level of Output: 0
        Type of Output/Format: mail / text
        Logfiles for Host: vmi514622.contaboserver.net
 ##################################################################
 
 --------------------- Amavisd-new Begin ------------------------

       37   Total messages scanned ------------------  100.00%
  307.387K  Total bytes scanned                        314,764
 ========   ==================================================
 
       37   Passed ----------------------------------  100.00%
       37     Clean passed                             100.00%
 ========   ==================================================
 
       37   Ham -------------------------------------  100.00%
       37     Clean passed                             100.00%
 ========   ==================================================
 
 
 ---------------------- Amavisd-new End -------------------------

 
 --------------------- pam_unix Begin ------------------------

 sshd:
    Authentication Failures:
       root (49.88.112.112): 76 Time(s)
       root (1.119.166.234): 65 Time(s)
       root (119.28.140.54): 64 Time(s)
       root (107.170.131.23): 63 Time(s)
       root (117.211.192.70): 59 Time(s)
       root (139.99.105.138): 59 Time(s)
       root (167.71.102.201): 59 Time(s)
       root (61.244.201.237): 58 Time(s)
       root (220.248.95.178): 55 Time(s)
       root (106.52.69.167): 54 Time(s)
       root (218.93.12.178): 53 Time(s)
       root (112.14.59.120): 50 Time(s)
       root (190.144.139.235): 50 Time(s)
       root (122.176.87.177): 48 Time(s)
       root (162.211.226.228): 48 Time(s)
       root (203.184.132.191): 48 Time(s)
       root (124.105.173.17): 47 Time(s)
       root (180.167.225.118): 46 Time(s)
       root (222.127.97.91): 46 Time(s)
       root (113.28.243.105): 45 Time(s)
       root (129.226.157.108): 45 Time(s)
       root (81.70.175.232): 45 Time(s)
       root (152.136.99.20): 42 Time(s)
       root (117.220.201.79): 40 Time(s)
       root (124.239.148.87): 40 Time(s)
       root (51.77.245.98): 40 Time(s)
       root (152.67.165.129): 39 Time(s)
       root (153.126.184.65): 39 Time(s)
       unknown (163.172.162.15): 39 Time(s)
       root (106.13.3.35): 38 Time(s)
       root (14.161.45.187): 38 Time(s)
       root (14.29.200.186): 38 Time(s)
       root (49.235.65.127): 37 Time(s)
       root (106.13.89.74): 36 Time(s)
       root (221.181.185.148): 36 Time(s)
       root (201.111.170.174): 34 Time(s)
       root (221.181.185.220): 32 Time(s)
       root (221.181.185.198): 28 Time(s)
       root (182.254.221.82): 27 Time(s)
       root (200.148.108.232): 27 Time(s)
       root (150.158.175.66): 25 Time(s)
       root (81.68.136.135): 25 Time(s)
       root (119.45.194.63): 23 Time(s)
       root (106.75.71.82): 22 Time(s)
       root (222.249.173.170): 22 Time(s)
       root (115.236.89.211): 20 Time(s)
       root (106.54.17.221): 19 Time(s)
       root (221.181.185.143): 16 Time(s)
       root (221.181.185.19): 16 Time(s)
       root (221.181.185.29): 16 Time(s)
       root (222.187.238.87): 16 Time(s)
       root (111.231.215.244): 15 Time(s)
       root (115.207.182.167): 15 Time(s)
       root (120.92.34.203): 15 Time(s)
       root (123.127.237.41): 15 Time(s)
       root (154.73.188.183): 15 Time(s)
       root (160.251.9.131): 15 Time(s)
       root (191.162.202.25): 15 Time(s)
       root (49.232.215.196): 15 Time(s)
       root (61.136.184.75): 15 Time(s)
       root (117.220.203.144): 14 Time(s)
       root (221.181.185.223): 14 Time(s)
       root (159.89.199.80): 13 Time(s)
       root (111.67.206.20): 12 Time(s)
       root (152.136.149.60): 12 Time(s)
       root (221.131.165.124): 12 Time(s)
       root (221.181.185.135): 12 Time(s)
       root (221.181.185.140): 12 Time(s)
       root (221.181.185.237): 12 Time(s)
       root (222.187.222.55): 12 Time(s)
       root (222.187.239.31): 12 Time(s)
       root (27.128.173.81): 12 Time(s)
       root (68.63.236.82): 12 Time(s)
       root (81.69.38.149): 12 Time(s)
       root (218.14.208.90): 11 Time(s)
       root (101.231.146.34): 10 Time(s)
       root (119.29.155.249): 10 Time(s)
       root (218.56.160.82): 10 Time(s)
       root (42.192.152.72): 10 Time(s)
       root (46.146.242.149): 10 Time(s)
       root (221.131.165.86): 8 Time(s)
       root (49.88.112.73): 8 Time(s)
       root (192.144.140.20): 7 Time(s)
       root (64.225.53.31): 7 Time(s)
       root (129.28.175.24): 6 Time(s)
       root (178.128.247.181): 6 Time(s)
       mail (163.172.162.15): 5 Time(s)
       root (161.97.126.91): 5 Time(s)
       root (167.86.90.235): 5 Time(s)
       root (186.121.204.10): 5 Time(s)
       root (212.64.71.254): 5 Time(s)
       root (27.155.193.17): 5 Time(s)
       root (49.232.87.218): 5 Time(s)
       root (68.183.156.109): 5 Time(s)
       root (152.136.209.192): 3 Time(s)
       unknown (159.203.29.235): 3 Time(s)
       root (103.232.91.46): 2 Time(s)
       unknown (141.98.80.29): 2 Time(s)
       unknown (141.98.80.90): 2 Time(s)
       unknown (141.98.80.93): 2 Time(s)
       unknown (165.22.85.95): 2 Time(s)
       unknown (195.206.105.217): 2 Time(s)
       unknown (91.173.12.250): 2 Time(s)
       root (115.159.90.137): 1 Time(s)
       root (122.161.194.250): 1 Time(s)
       root (141.98.80.89): 1 Time(s)
       root (141.98.80.91): 1 Time(s)
       root (141.98.80.92): 1 Time(s)
       root (150.136.243.33): 1 Time(s)
       root (151.106.113.19): 1 Time(s)
       root (151.253.125.137): 1 Time(s)
       root (152.32.252.163): 1 Time(s)
       root (154.120.242.70): 1 Time(s)
       root (157.230.90.18): 1 Time(s)
       root (157.245.140.49): 1 Time(s)
       root (167.172.233.156): 1 Time(s)
       root (176.121.235.86): 1 Time(s)
       root (178.33.67.12): 1 Time(s)
       root (182.61.144.129): 1 Time(s)
       root (187.45.103.15): 1 Time(s)
       root (217.128.133.129): 1 Time(s)
       root (218.103.15.177): 1 Time(s)
       root (36.133.163.35): 1 Time(s)
       root (45.80.153.199): 1 Time(s)
       root (49.232.2.249): 1 Time(s)
       root (81.68.253.95): 1 Time(s)
       root (86.131.53.144): 1 Time(s)
       root (89.71.241.168): 1 Time(s)
       root (93.188.164.171): 1 Time(s)
       unknown (141.98.80.89): 1 Time(s)
       unknown (141.98.80.91): 1 Time(s)
       unknown (141.98.80.92): 1 Time(s)
    Invalid Users:
       Unknown Account: 57 Time(s)
 
 su:
    Authentication Failures:
       root(1000) -> root: 1 Time(s)
    Sessions Opened:
       root -> iredadmin: 1 Time(s)
       root -> iredapd: 1 Time(s)
       root -> netdata: 1 Time(s)
       root -> root: 1 Time(s)
       root -> vlado: 1 Time(s)
       root -> vmail: 1 Time(s)
 
 sudo:
    Sessions Opened:
       root -> root: 14 Time(s)
 
 
 ---------------------- pam_unix End -------------------------

 
 --------------------- Postfix Begin ------------------------

        1   Connections                                      1
        1   Disconnections                                   1
       32   Postscreen                                      32
 
        1   TLS connections (server)                         1
        1   TLS connections (client)                         1
 
 
 
 **Unmatched Entries**
        1   Mar  1 10:29:55 vmi514622 postfix/cleanup[1196156]: 4Dpw2p75TJzPkbt: message-id=<461606523.16.1614590994536@vmi503579.contaboserver.net>
        1   Mar  1 10:36:33 vmi514622 postfix/qmgr[46456]: 4DpwBT5nq3zPkdb: from=<postmaster@tatrytec.eu>, size=4708, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
        1   Mar  1 12:24:23 vmi514622 postfix/cleanup[1200919]: 4DpyZv4FZTzPkdg: message-id=<1444320002.30.1614597862581@vmi503579.contaboserver.net>
        1   Mar  1 20:14:18 vmi514622 postfix/qmgr[46456]: 4Dq9152GSBzPkbt: removed
        1   Mar  1 22:43:50 vmi514622 postfix/qmgr[46456]: 4DqDKW28dzzPkbt: removed
        1   Mar  1 21:34:50 vmi514622 postfix/cleanup[1222763]: 4DqBp26MQdzPkbt: message-id=<948563194.49.1614630890438@vmi503579.contaboserver.net>
        1   Mar  1 15:25:21 vmi514622 postfix/pipe[1207882]: 4Dq2bj19CbzPkdg: to=<postmaster@tatrytec.eu>, relay=dovecot, delay=0.13, delays=0.01/0.01/0/0.11, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (delivered via dovecot service)
        1   Mar  1 10:24:26 vmi514622 postfix/pipe[1195937]: 4DpvwT3ynvzPkdB: to=<postmaster@tatrytec.eu>, relay=dovecot, delay=0.48, delays=0.02/0.04/0/0.42, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (delivered via dovecot service)
        1   Mar  1 03:30:06 vmi514622 postfix/cleanup[1177579]: 4DpkkQ5bHKzPkdg: message-id=<4DpkkM0BsnzPkdc@vmi514622.contaboserver.net>
        1   Mar  1 11:20:47 vmi514622 postfix/pipe[1198348]: 4Dpx9W0njGzPkdg: to=<postmaster@tatrytec.eu>, relay=dovecot, delay=0.17, delays=0.01/0.02/0/0.14, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (delivered via dovecot service)
        1   Mar  1 21:25:24 vmi514622 postfix/qmgr[46456]: 4DqBb81DvVzPkdg: removed
        1   Mar  1 16:50:19 vmi514622 postfix/cleanup[1211187]: 4Dq4Tl4g7GzPkbt: message-id=<2100803903.33.1614613818814@vmi503579.contaboserver.net>
        1   Mar  1 20:55:33 vmi514622 postfix/qmgr[46456]: 4Dq9wj3HY7zPkbt: from=<postmaster@tatrytec.eu>, size=6266, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
        1   Mar  1 06:26:20 vmi514622 postfix/cleanup[1185400]: 4Dppdm1cvrzPkdj: message-id=<4Dppdh3zd9zPkdg@vmi514622.contaboserver.net>
        1   Mar  1 12:25:09 vmi514622 postfix/cleanup[1200919]: 4Dpybn49tpzPkdg: message-id=<348486365.31.1614597909063@vmi503579.contaboserver.net>
        1   Mar  1 21:49:08 vmi514622 postfix/qmgr[46456]: 4DqC6V1qxxzPkbt: removed
        1   Mar  1 21:34:51 vmi514622 postfix/pipe[1222768]: 4DqBp32pZTzPkdg: to=<postmaster@tatrytec.eu>, relay=dovecot, delay=0.05, delays=0.01/0.01/0/0.03, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (delivered via dovecot service)
        1   Mar  1 11:26:52 vmi514622 postfix/qmgr[46456]: 4DpxJX12dvzPkbt: removed
        1   Mar  1 12:25:09 vmi514622 postfix/cleanup[1200919]: 4Dpybn2NYMzPkbt: message-id=<348486365.31.1614597909063@vmi503579.contaboserver.net>
        1   Mar  1 10:25:03 vmi514622 postfix/qmgr[46456]: 4DpvxC2tj6zPkdH: from=<postmaster@tatrytec.eu>, size=7438, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
        1   Mar  1 21:49:06 vmi514622 postfix/cleanup[1223355]: 4DqC6V1qxxzPkbt: message-id=<1666648692.51.1614631745669@vmi503579.contaboserver.net>
        1   Mar  1 22:43:43 vmi514622 postfix/qmgr[46456]: 4DqDKW28dzzPkbt: from=<postmaster@tatrytec.eu>, size=6124, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
        1   Mar  1 10:25:03 vmi514622 postfix/qmgr[46456]: 4DpvxC2tj6zPkdH: removed
        1   Mar  1 04:00:08 vmi514622 postfix/cleanup[1178958]: 4DplP44YsczPkdg: message-id=<4DplP2288zzPkdg@vmi514622.contaboserver.net>
        1   Mar  1 10:54:17 vmi514622 postfix/cleanup[1197185]: 4DpwZx1CnxzPkbt: message-id=<1674123124.20.1614592456622@vmi503579.contaboserver.net>
        1   Mar  1 20:55:34 vmi514622 postfix/qmgr[46456]: 4Dq9wk33zVzPkdg: removed
        1   Mar  1 20:45:09 vmi514622 postfix/cleanup[1220774]: 4Dq9hj1vh8zPkbt: message-id=<580959423.41.1614627908734@vmi503579.contaboserver.net>
        1   Mar  1 11:20:47 vmi514622 postfix/qmgr[46456]: 4Dpx9T2Y3BzPkbt: removed
        1   Mar  1 20:45:10 vmi514622 postfix/qmgr[46456]: 4Dq9hk16kBzPkdg: removed
        1   Mar  1 11:25:09 vmi514622 postfix/cleanup[1198541]: 4DpxGY2lHyzPkbt: message-id=<88426377.23.1614594308967@vmi503579.contaboserver.net>
        1   Mar  1 11:25:52 vmi514622 postfix/qmgr[46456]: 4DpxHN45bqzPkdg: removed
        1   Mar  1 10:54:17 vmi514622 postfix/qmgr[46456]: 4DpwZx1CnxzPkbt: removed
        1   Mar  1 16:50:20 vmi514622 postfix/qmgr[46456]: 4Dq4Tl4g7GzPkbt: removed
        1   Mar  1 11:20:47 vmi514622 postfix/qmgr[46456]: 4Dpx9W0njGzPkdg: from=<postmaster@tatrytec.eu>, size=23083, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
        1   Mar  1 04:01:02 vmi514622 postfix/qmgr[46456]: 4DplQ65lDTzPkdg: from=<root@vmi514622.contaboserver.net>, size=855, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
        1   Mar  1 10:25:02 vmi514622 postfix/qmgr[46456]: 4DpvxB4jmRzPkbt: from=<postmaster@tatrytec.eu>, size=6055, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
        1   Mar  1 12:25:09 vmi514622 postfix/qmgr[46456]: 4Dpybn2NYMzPkbt: from=<postmaster@tatrytec.eu>, size=1318, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
        1   Mar  1 17:37:06 vmi514622 postfix/qmgr[46456]: 4Dq5Wk2KFMzPkdg: from=<vladimir.camaj@gmail.com>, size=96198, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
        1   Mar  1 04:01:04 vmi514622 postfix/qmgr[46456]: 4DplQ80YwqzPkdc: from=<root@vmi514622.contaboserver.net>, size=2223, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
        1   Mar  1 17:34:49 vmi514622 postfix/pipe[1213041]: 4Dq5T474YtzPkdg: to=<postmaster@tatrytec.eu>, relay=dovecot, delay=0.1, delays=0.03/0.02/0/0.05, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (delivered via dovecot service)
        1   Mar  1 21:49:08 vmi514622 postfix/qmgr[46456]: 4DqC6X1tg2zPkdg: from=<postmaster@tatrytec.eu>, size=7651, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
        1   Mar  1 06:26:20 vmi514622 postfix/local[1185425]: 4Dppdm1TB7zPkdc: to=<root@vmi514622.contaboserver.net>, relay=local, delay=0.03, delays=0.01/0.01/0/0.01, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (forwarded as 4Dppdm1cvrzPkdj)
        1   Mar  1 04:01:04 vmi514622 postfix/cleanup[1178958]: 4DplQ80YwqzPkdc: message-id=<4DplQ65lDTzPkdg@vmi514622.contaboserver.net>
        1   Mar  1 20:45:10 vmi514622 postfix/cleanup[1220774]: 4Dq9hk16kBzPkdg: message-id=<580959423.41.1614627908734@vmi503579.contaboserver.net>
        1   Mar  1 11:36:23 vmi514622 postfix/pipe[1198903]: 4DpxWV6dHtzPkdg: to=<postmaster@tatrytec.eu>, relay=dovecot, delay=0.08, delays=0.01/0.02/0/0.06, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (delivered via dovecot service)
        1   Mar  1 11:18:37 vmi514622 postfix/pipe[1198261]: 4Dpx711q91zPkdg: to=<postmaster@tatrytec.eu>, relay=dovecot, delay=0.16, delays=0.03/0.04/0/0.09, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (delivered via dovecot service)
        1   Mar  1 11:20:45 vmi514622 postfix/qmgr[46456]: 4Dpx9T2Y3BzPkbt: from=<postmaster@tatrytec.eu>, size=21700, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
        1   Mar  1 10:41:00 vmi514622 postfix/pipe[1196674]: 4DpwHc5S2xzPkdg: to=<postmaster@tatrytec.eu>, relay=dovecot, delay=0.07, delays=0.01/0.01/0/0.05, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (delivered via dovecot service)
        1   Mar  1 12:09:26 vmi514622 postfix/pipe[1200352]: 4DpyFf5PhZzPkdg: to=<postmaster@tatrytec.eu>, relay=dovecot, delay=0.15, delays=0.01/0.02/0/0.12, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (delivered via dovecot service)
        1   Mar  1 17:34:49 vmi514622 postfix/qmgr[46456]: 4Dq5Sy23z9zPkbt: removed
        1   Mar  1 11:35:36 vmi514622 postfix/cleanup[1198898]: 4DpxVc5dHhzPkbt: message-id=<1508325983.26.1614594936339@vmi503579.contaboserver.net>
        1   Mar  1 11:36:22 vmi514622 postfix/cleanup[1198898]: 4DpxWV3rTNzPkbt: message-id=<2063571191.27.1614594982264@vmi503579.contaboserver.net>
        1   Mar  1 20:45:10 vmi514622 postfix/qmgr[46456]: 4Dq9hj1vh8zPkbt: removed
        1   Mar  1 04:00:06 vmi514622 postfix/pickup[1177877]: 4DplP2288zzPkdg: uid=0 from=<root>
        1   Mar  1 10:30:29 vmi514622 postfix/cleanup[1196156]: 4Dpw3T3XCYzPkbt: message-id=<1109215425.17.1614591029166@vmi503579.contaboserver.net>
        1   Mar  1 10:28:10 vmi514622 postfix/cleanup[1196074]: 4Dpw0p0QkkzPkbt: message-id=<1610853501.15.1614590889586@vmi503579.contaboserver.net>
        1   Mar  1 12:20:56 vmi514622 postfix/qmgr[46456]: 4DpyVw3JlSzPkdg: removed
        1   Mar  1 17:37:05 vmi514622 postfix/cleanup[1213164]: 4Dq5Wj33ZnzPkbt: message-id=<CACBSb5ZvgNzda5Bwz_UKqsvBpDvreak4g+UgwCTfQrVSnLrW=g@mail.gmail.com>
        1   Mar  1 04:01:04 vmi514622 postfix/qmgr[46456]: 4DplQ80YwqzPkdc: removed
        1   Mar  1 04:00:08 vmi514622 postfix/qmgr[46456]: 4DplP2288zzPkdg: removed
        1   Mar  1 06:26:16 vmi514622 postfix/cleanup[1185400]: 4Dppdh3zd9zPkdg: message-id=<4Dppdh3zd9zPkdg@vmi514622.contaboserver.net>
        1   Mar  1 12:20:56 vmi514622 postfix/qmgr[46456]: 4DpyVp4G02zPkbt: removed
        1   Mar  1 20:55:34 vmi514622 postfix/qmgr[46456]: 4Dq9wk33zVzPkdg: from=<postmaster@tatrytec.eu>, size=7649, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
        1   Mar  1 12:24:23 vmi514622 postfix/qmgr[46456]: 4DpyZv4FZTzPkdg: from=<postmaster@tatrytec.eu>, size=6965, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
        1   Mar  1 22:43:43 vmi514622 postfix/cleanup[1225466]: 4DqDKW28dzzPkbt: message-id=<1333430951.52.1614635022798@vmi503579.contaboserver.net>
        1   Mar  1 04:00:06 vmi514622 postfix/cleanup[1178958]: 4DplP2288zzPkdg: message-id=<4DplP2288zzPkdg@vmi514622.contaboserver.net>
        1   Mar  1 03:30:03 vmi514622 postfix/cleanup[1177579]: 4DpkkM0BsnzPkdc: message-id=<4DpkkM0BsnzPkdc@vmi514622.contaboserver.net>
        1   Mar  1 11:20:47 vmi514622 postfix/qmgr[46456]: 4Dpx9W0njGzPkdg: removed
        1   Mar  1 10:28:10 vmi514622 postfix/qmgr[46456]: 4Dpw0p0QkkzPkbt: removed
        1   Mar  1 11:18:35 vmi514622 postfix/cleanup[1198256]: 4Dpx6z6dVszPkbt: message-id=<1098013570.21.1614593915103@vmi503579.contaboserver.net>
        1   Mar  1 04:01:02 vmi514622 postfix/cleanup[1178958]: 4DplQ65lDTzPkdg: message-id=<4DplQ65lDTzPkdg@vmi514622.contaboserver.net>
        1   Mar  1 03:30:06 vmi514622 postfix/cleanup[1177579]: 4DpkkQ5nLqzPkdj: message-id=<4DpkkM0BsnzPkdc@vmi514622.contaboserver.net>
        1   Mar  1 11:36:23 vmi514622 postfix/qmgr[46456]: 4DpxWV6dHtzPkdg: removed
        1   Mar  1 10:28:10 vmi514622 postfix/cleanup[1196074]: 4Dpw0p6CRPzPkdM: message-id=<1610853501.15.1614590889586@vmi503579.contaboserver.net>
        1   Mar  1 17:37:06 vmi514622 postfix/pipe[1213175]: 4Dq5Wk2KFMzPkdg: to=<postmaster@tatrytec.eu>, relay=dovecot, delay=0.07, delays=0.01/0.01/0/0.04, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (delivered via dovecot service)
        1   Mar  1 11:25:52 vmi514622 postfix/cleanup[1198541]: 4DpxHN1Y3nzPkbt: message-id=<1629541888.24.1614594351875@vmi503579.contaboserver.net>
        1   Mar  1 10:24:25 vmi514622 postfix/qmgr[46456]: 4DpvwS4Jv6zPkbt: removed
        1   Mar  1 15:25:10 vmi514622 postfix/qmgr[46456]: 4Dq2bV1DXMzPkbt: from=<postmaster@tatrytec.eu>, size=6101, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
        1   Mar  1 10:41:00 vmi514622 postfix/qmgr[46456]: 4DpwHc24GqzPkbt: removed
        1   Mar  1 20:45:10 vmi514622 postfix/smtp[1220779]: 4Dq9hk16kBzPkdg: to=<vladimir.camaj@gmail.com>, relay=gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[108.177.126.27]:25, delay=0.57, delays=0.01/0.02/0.13/0.41, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 OK  1614627910 i12si11266553ejr.344 - gsmtp)
        1   Mar  1 09:04:18 vmi514622 postfix/pipe[1192514]: 4Dpt8227gKzPkcx: to=<postmaster@tatrytec.eu>, relay=dovecot, delay=0.1, delays=0.01/0.01/0/0.08, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (delivered via dovecot service)
        1   Mar  1 04:01:04 vmi514622 postfix/qmgr[46456]: 4DplQ65lDTzPkdg: removed
        1   Mar  1 03:30:03 vmi514622 postfix/qmgr[46456]: 4DpkkM0BsnzPkdc: from=<root@vmi514622.contaboserver.net>, size=1299, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
        1   Mar  1 11:25:09 vmi514622 postfix/pipe[1198546]: 4DpxGY5ZdtzPkdg: to=<postmaster@tatrytec.eu>, relay=dovecot, delay=0.05, delays=0.01/0.01/0/0.04, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (delivered via dovecot service)
        1   Mar  1 10:36:33 vmi514622 postfix/pipe[1196443]: 4DpwBT5nq3zPkdb: to=<postmaster@tatrytec.eu>, relay=dovecot, delay=0.14, delays=0.02/0.02/0/0.11, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (delivered via dovecot service)
        1   Mar  1 11:20:45 vmi514622 postfix/cleanup[1198341]: 4Dpx9T2Y3BzPkbt: message-id=<457956705.22.1614594044942@vmi503579.contaboserver.net>
        1   Mar  1 23:12:41 vmi514622 postfix/qmgr[46456]: 4DqDyq4pnFzPkbt: removed
        1   Mar  1 23:12:35 vmi514622 postfix/qmgr[46456]: 4DqDyq4pnFzPkbt: from=<postmaster@tatrytec.eu>, size=6163, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
        1   Mar  1 10:41:00 vmi514622 postfix/qmgr[46456]: 4DpwHc24GqzPkbt: from=<postmaster@tatrytec.eu>, size=3324, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
        1   Mar  1 12:20:56 vmi514622 postfix/cleanup[1200775]: 4DpyVw3JlSzPkdg: message-id=<991290979.29.1614597650185@vmi503579.contaboserver.net>
        1   Mar  1 20:45:10 vmi514622 postfix/qmgr[46456]: 4Dq9hk16kBzPkdg: from=<postmaster@tatrytec.eu>, size=1968, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
        1   Mar  1 10:25:03 vmi514622 postfix/pipe[1195937]: 4DpvxC2tj6zPkdH: to=<postmaster@tatrytec.eu>, relay=dovecot, delay=0.05, delays=0/0.02/0/0.03, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (delivered via dovecot service)
        1   Mar  1 12:20:50 vmi514622 postfix/cleanup[1200775]: 4DpyVp4G02zPkbt: message-id=<991290979.29.1614597650185@vmi503579.contaboserver.net>
        1   Mar  1 12:09:14 vmi514622 postfix/qmgr[46456]: 4DpyFQ6K9pzPkbt: from=<postmaster@tatrytec.eu>, size=3324, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
        1   Mar  1 10:30:30 vmi514622 postfix/qmgr[46456]: 4Dpw3V0k5lzPkdW: removed
        1   Mar  1 11:26:52 vmi514622 postfix/cleanup[1198541]: 4DpxJX3v27zPkdg: message-id=<495459168.25.1614594411827@vmi503579.contaboserver.net>
        1   Mar  1 20:55:34 vmi514622 postfix/pipe[1221178]: 4Dq9wk33zVzPkdg: to=<postmaster@tatrytec.eu>, relay=dovecot, delay=0.13, delays=0.01/0.02/0/0.1, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (delivered via dovecot service)
        1   Mar  1 15:25:21 vmi514622 postfix/qmgr[46456]: 4Dq2bj19CbzPkdg: from=<postmaster@tatrytec.eu>, size=7458, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
        1   Mar  1 12:09:26 vmi514622 postfix/cleanup[1200333]: 4DpyFf5PhZzPkdg: message-id=<518461345.28.1614596954418@vmi503579.contaboserver.net>
        1   Mar  1 23:12:41 vmi514622 postfix/qmgr[46456]: 4DqDyx2nnczPkdg: removed
        1   Mar  1 11:26:52 vmi514622 postfix/pipe[1198546]: 4DpxJX3v27zPkdg: to=<postmaster@tatrytec.eu>, relay=dovecot, delay=0.05, delays=0/0.02/0/0.03, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (delivered via dovecot service)
        1   Mar  1 09:04:18 vmi514622 postfix/qmgr[46456]: 4Dpt813WSdzPkbt: removed
        1   Mar  1 04:00:08 vmi514622 postfix/qmgr[46456]: 4DplP43wYCzPkdc: from=<root@vmi514622.contaboserver.net>, size=2769, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
        1   Mar  1 12:24:23 vmi514622 postfix/pipe[1200924]: 4DpyZv4FZTzPkdg: to=<postmaster@tatrytec.eu>, relay=dovecot, delay=0.07, delays=0.01/0.02/0/0.04, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (delivered via dovecot service)
        1   Mar  1 06:26:20 vmi514622 postfix/qmgr[46456]: 4Dppdm1TB7zPkdc: from=<root@vmi514622.contaboserver.net>, size=32737, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
        1   Mar  1 21:20:25 vmi514622 postfix/qmgr[46456]: 4DqBTN6l1SzPkdg: removed
        1   Mar  1 11:35:37 vmi514622 postfix/qmgr[46456]: 4DpxVc5dHhzPkbt: removed
        1   Mar  1 16:50:20 vmi514622 postfix/cleanup[1211187]: 4Dq4Tm5kDYzPkdg: message-id=<2100803903.33.1614613818814@vmi503579.contaboserver.net>
        1   Mar  1 10:29:55 vmi514622 postfix/qmgr[46456]: 4Dpw2p75TJzPkbt: removed
        1   Mar  1 03:30:06 vmi514622 postfix/qmgr[46456]: 4DpkkM0BsnzPkdc: removed
        1   Mar  1 12:24:23 vmi514622 postfix/cleanup[1200919]: 4DpyZv01YCzPkbt: message-id=<1444320002.30.1614597862581@vmi503579.contaboserver.net>
        1   Mar  1 10:30:30 vmi514622 postfix/qmgr[46456]: 4Dpw3V0k5lzPkdW: from=<postmaster@tatrytec.eu>, size=6965, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
        1   Mar  1 22:43:50 vmi514622 postfix/cleanup[1225466]: 4DqDKf3H3CzPkdg: message-id=<1333430951.52.1614635022798@vmi503579.contaboserver.net>
        1   Mar  1 10:36:33 vmi514622 postfix/qmgr[46456]: 4DpwBT0K56zPkbt: from=<postmaster@tatrytec.eu>, size=3325, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
        1   Mar  1 20:14:17 vmi514622 postfix/qmgr[46456]: 4Dq9152GSBzPkbt: from=<postmaster@tatrytec.eu>, size=6271, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
        1   Mar  1 10:24:24 vmi514622 postfix/qmgr[46456]: 4DpvwS4Jv6zPkbt: from=<postmaster@tatrytec.eu>, size=6054, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
        1   Mar  1 06:26:20 vmi514622 postfix/pipe[1185426]: 4Dppdm1cvrzPkdj: to=<postmaster@tatrytec.eu>, orig_to=<root@vmi514622.contaboserver.net>, relay=dovecot, delay=0.14, delays=0/0.01/0/0.12, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (delivered via dovecot service)
        1   Mar  1 23:12:41 vmi514622 postfix/pipe[1226661]: 4DqDyx2nnczPkdg: to=<postmaster@tatrytec.eu>, relay=dovecot, delay=0.05, delays=0/0.01/0/0.04, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (delivered via dovecot service)
        1   Mar  1 06:26:16 vmi514622 postfix/qmgr[46456]: 4Dppdh3zd9zPkdg: from=<root@vmi514622.contaboserver.net>, size=31358, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
        1   Mar  1 10:30:30 vmi514622 postfix/qmgr[46456]: 4Dpw3T3XCYzPkbt: removed
        1   Mar  1 21:20:24 vmi514622 postfix/qmgr[46456]: 4DqBTN6l1SzPkdg: from=<postmaster@tatrytec.eu>, size=7484, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
        1   Mar  1 10:41:00 vmi514622 postfix/qmgr[46456]: 4DpwHc5S2xzPkdg: removed
        1   Mar  1 04:00:06 vmi514622 postfix/qmgr[46456]: 4DplP2288zzPkdg: from=<root@vmi514622.contaboserver.net>, size=1389, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
        1   Mar  1 21:34:51 vmi514622 postfix/qmgr[46456]: 4DqBp32pZTzPkdg: from=<postmaster@tatrytec.eu>, size=7647, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
        1   Mar  1 17:34:49 vmi514622 postfix/cleanup[1213036]: 4Dq5T474YtzPkdg: message-id=<1185830453.37.1614616481862@vmi503579.contaboserver.net>
        1   Mar  1 06:26:16 vmi514622 postfix/pickup[1182116]: 4Dppdh3zd9zPkdg: uid=0 from=<root>
        1   Mar  1 03:30:06 vmi514622 postfix/local[1177589]: 4DpkkQ5bHKzPkdg: to=<root@vmi514622.contaboserver.net>, relay=local, delay=0.03, delays=0.01/0.01/0/0.01, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (forwarded as 4DpkkQ5nLqzPkdj)
        1   Mar  1 03:30:07 vmi514622 postfix/pipe[1177591]: 4DpkkQ5nLqzPkdj: to=<postmaster@tatrytec.eu>, orig_to=<root@vmi514622.contaboserver.net>, relay=dovecot, delay=0.19, delays=0/0.01/0/0.18, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (delivered via dovecot service)
        1   Mar  1 04:01:04 vmi514622 postfix/qmgr[46456]: 4DplQ80f1PzPkdj: from=<root@vmi514622.contaboserver.net>, size=2383, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
        1   Mar  1 10:28:10 vmi514622 postfix/qmgr[46456]: 4Dpw0p6CRPzPkdM: from=
 
 ---------------------- Postfix End -------------------------

 
 --------------------- rsyslogd Begin ------------------------

 Rsyslogd actions suspended:
    action-6-builtin:omfile (builtin:omfile): 15531 Times
 
 Rsyslogd actions resumed
    action-6-builtin:omfile (builtin:omfile): 14120 Times
 
 **** Unmatched entries ****
     file '/var/log/fail2ban.log': open error: Permission denied [v8.2001.0 try https://www.rsyslog.com/e/2433 ] : 1 Times
 
 ---------------------- rsyslogd End -------------------------
```

I am not sure but I read somewhere that UFW is able to block number of failed logins from one IP within  30 seconds window. I dont know but in the log there are really hundreds of attempts. Or is it the log from the time when the firewall was not set yet? I set it about 12 hours ago. Is my firewall right? Thanks a lot for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is just normal noise of the `www`. If you use strong passwords, it is nothing to worry about.

However there are some measures you should take to lower the noise and make your server more secure:

- Disable `root` login, rather login as normal user and use `sudo`.
- Disable `password` login and use `pubkey`-authentication only
- Change your `ssh` port to some higher port number (make sure to allow it in your firewall).
- Install `fail2ban` to at least delay these attempts.
- Use strong passwords **anywhere**
- Keep all software up to date at any time

[See also for more information](https://serverfault.com/questions/244614/is-it-normal-to-get-hundreds-of-break-in-attempts-per-day).

---

`ufw limit` and `fail2ban` are nice to have, but attackers know about these limits and make just as many attempts that they won't get blocked. Usually these random attacks are done via some botnet of random servers taken over, so the effect of limiting attempts per IP is limited.

Comment: I changed the ssh port to 2625 and also root login in sshd_conf to PermitRootLogin without-password and now I am not able to login :D

Comment: Did you set `ufw` to allow `2625` ? And did you set up (and tested) keybased authentication before disabling password auth? Your VPS provider might have a ssh-console in their interface from which you might be able to connect. Otherwise you have to ask their support ...

Comment: Yes key auth works but I mean port 2625 is closed. I did not allow it in UFW That could be the problem.

Comment: Is there any way to log in before I will call the support?

Comment: No. Only if the providers interface provides a web-based ssh console.

Comment: No it does not. Hope they are able to change it from inside. I dont know if is it able to access VPS from the system which it is running on like it is inside local connection? Hope so.

Comment: I have it. Now I know why they send me VNC credentials. Have a nice day.

Comment: Good! glad, that you could solve it ;-)